# how to add images to a panel at any location (x,y)

Tags: java, swing

i want to add images or labels with image in it to a panel at any location which will be decided by the user clicking on the panel(add image where user clicks in the panel).
how to do this.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try (and tweak) this [sscce](http://sscce.org):

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class JLabelOnClick extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    final JFrame frame = new JLabelOnClick();
    final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(null);
    frame.setContentPane(panel);

    frame.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        // if you want an image instead, use the JLabel(Icon image)
        // constructor
        JLabel label = new JLabel("test");
        label.setBounds(e.getX(), e.getY(), label.getPreferredSize().width, label
            .getPreferredSize().height);
        panel.add(label);
        panel.validate();
        frame.repaint();
        }
    });

    frame.setSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

set `null` as LayoutManager for that panel and then manually set position for each image.